# How can i add this validation to form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs;
var left, opacity, scale;
var animating;
$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;
    current_fs = $(this).parent().parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().parent().next();
    $(".progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");
    next_fs.show(); 
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        }, 
        duration: 800, 
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        }, 
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});



bla bla bla
});
```

and i have a validation code

```
$(':text').each(function(){
        if(this.value.length==0){
            $(this).addClass('animated bounce')
               .one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
               $(this).removeClass()
            });
        }
    });
```

how can i add this validation to next click function? of course if value lenght 0 next action must be kill. Codes are more prev, submit bla bla bla everything is working but just i need this validation integration to next click function.

Thanks help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly. Enclose the validation code to a function, and add a return variable as shown below. This variable will be set to false when any of your :text has an empty string.

```
function isValidText(){
    var isValid = true;
    $(':text').each(function(){
        if(this.value.length==0){
            isValid = false;
            $(this).addClass('animated bounce')
                   .one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
                $(this).removeClass()
            });
        }
    });
    return isValid;
}
```

Then in your main code, change the validation to this:

```
$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating || !isValidText()) return false;
    . . .
```

Comment: just i want to add a validation to next action when i click next if inputs lenght 0 not go to next @ochiboy thank you

Comment: Yes, that is what I had in mind in doing this code. If isValidText returns false, it will be interpreted as true, and the line  
if(animating || !isValidText()) return false; will immediately return false and will not run the click function.